# How do I webscrape some text that is grouped with an image

Tags: c#, web-scraping

So I'm completely new to webscraping and generally all around not good at coding, but I just can't seem to get how webscraping works, it just seems so messy?

Anyway, I'm trying to webscrape the team names from https://siege.gg/matches/5901-nal-na-tsm-ftx-vs-mirage (Being Mirage and TSM FTX) using HtmlAgilityPack. Now I can get the top two where it first displays their names by doing...

```
var teamNames = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2/a/span[@class='match__name']");
        foreach (var i in teamNames)
        {
            if (i.InnerText != null)
            {
                string teamName = i.InnerText;
                teamsList.Add(teamName.Substring(1));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Team not found");
            }
        }
```

But this sometimes has the team names the wrong way round to the table down below. Therefore I'm only left with the choice to scrape from the table, however, I just can't seem to choose a path that leads there.
Does anyone have any ideas?

[This is where I need the text "Mirage" from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZJBQ.png)

Comment: Web scraping is a messy business. You are trying to gather information from a medium (HTML) not intended for machine to machine communication, you are doing it without the cooperation of the third party, and even without their knowledge that you are doing so. The third party can change the HTML of their website at any time for any reason, invalidating instantly your web-scraping code.

Comment: I know but I have no choice :( . Their api is lacking and some other api's cost money I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you successfully started your first web scraping project :) You managed to get steps 1-4 below, maybe also step 5.

You basically do it like this:

1. Identify the target website
2. Collect URLs of the pages where you want to extract data from
3. Make a request to these URLs to get the HTML of the page
4. Use locators to find the data in the HTML
5. Save the data in any structured format

I have tested your code on [.netfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) and it works fine. (I could not save it, but you can easily copy and paste my test code and run your own test.)

In my test code below, I have not used an array but just outputted the names. The first name is outputted first.

```
// @nuget: HtmlAgilityPack

using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        
        var html = 
        @"<div class=""container""><div class=""row no-gutters mx-md-n1 match__header"">
           <div class=""col-12 col-md match__overview px-md-1 align-self-stretch team--a"">
              <h2 class=""match__overview-upper h3""> <a href=""/teams/47"" class=""match__team link-inherit p-0""> <span class=""match__flag mx-2""> <img class=""flag flag--us w-1"" src=""https://staff-cdn.siege.gg/flags/us.svg"" alt=""US Flagge"" title=""US Flagge""> </span> <span class=""match__name""> TSM FTX </span> </a> </h2>
              <div class=""match__overview-lower rounded overflow-hidden"">
                 <a href=""/teams/47"" class=""d-block match__logo""> <img class=""match__logo__img img-fluid"" src=""https://staff-cdn.siege.gg/org-473-tsm.png"" alt=""TSM FTX Logo""> </a> 
                 <div class=""match__score loss align-content-stretch""> 6 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class=""col-12 col-md match__overview px-md-1 align-self-stretch team--b"">
              <h2 class=""match__overview-upper h3""> <a href=""/teams/478"" class=""match__team link-inherit p-0""> <span class=""match__flag mx-2""> <img class=""flag flag--us w-1"" src=""https://staff-cdn.siege.gg/flags/us.svg"" alt=""US Flagge"" title=""US Flagge""> </span> <span class=""match__name""> Mirage </span> </a> </h2>
              <div class=""match__overview-lower rounded overflow-hidden"">
                 <a href=""/teams/478"" class=""d-block match__logo""> <img class=""match__logo__img img-fluid"" src=""https://staff-cdn.siege.gg/org-676-mrg.png"" alt=""Mirage Logo""> </a> 
                 <div class=""match__score win align-content-stretch""> 8 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>";
        
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        var teamNames = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2/a/span[@class='match__name']");
        foreach (var i in teamNames)
        {
            if (i.InnerText != null)
            {
                string teamName = i.InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(teamName.Substring(1));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Team not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update after your update:

You can easily test any part of the hmtl like this using fiddle. In this case, I used the class of the td element with the a tag:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        
        var html = 
        @"<td class=""js-heatmap-ignore"" colspan=""100""><a href=""/teams/478"" class=""link-inherit""><img src=""https://staff-cdn.siege.gg/org-676-mrg.png"" class=""w-2 h-2 object-fit-contain mr-2"">Mirage</a></td>";
        
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
        var teamNames = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='js-heatmap-ignore']/a");
        foreach (var i in teamNames)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(i.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast, but this still doesn't solve my problem. I can get the match names as you showed with the this path "//h2/a/span[@class='match__name']", but this sometimes makes the teams the wrong way round to the scoreboard, so I have to scrape it from the actual scoreboard on the website. 
I've edited my original question to show you where it is, but i can't seem to scrape it from there.

Comment: I tested a bit more, very interesting topic. See my updated code.